# How to reset @GenereatedValue sequence value for entity

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, h2

I have an entity (Product) which has an ID column

```
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class ProductEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
```

I would like to be able to reset this generated value.

I am running tests against an in memory DB H2, and between each test I am deleting all my products.

```
 productRepository.deleteAll();
```

The problem is that when I repopulate my product table with for example 3 new products, instead of the ID numbers being 1,2,3, they are 4,5,6.

This is creating inconsistent data and is breaking some of my tests. The only way my tests work is if I restart my spring server.

Answer (score 1):

Execute this statement directly: truncate table

This statement will clear the data and reset the self growing primary key

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE tableName RESTART IDENTITY` is actually required unless MySQL, MariaDB, or MSSQLServer compatibility mode is enabled (in these modes restart is performed by default).